# How to send a gmail with starred using java mail api

Tags: java, email, gmail

I tried to use Java mail API to send a gmail with starred. I read in many places and I added code as follows:-

```
if (mailHighPriority) {
               msg.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");
               msg.setHeader("Importance", "high");
               msg.setHeader("priority", "Urgent");
               msg.setHeader("x-msmail-priority", "high");
           }
```

However, I am not able to set the Gmail as starred. Is there any other option for this? Thanks

Comment: Did you get to know how to do it?

Comment: No. Let me know if you got one.

Answer (score 0):

STARRED is a label used by gmail. You can't set a label when sending a mail.
You need to set up a filtering rule or use the gmail api to apply labels to messages.